# Call variable outside while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a simple code here:

```
$rand     = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
$sid      = array(
    ":sponsorID" => $rand
);
$accounts = $db->select("accounts", "sponsorID = :sponsorID", $sid);
while (count($accounts) > 0) {

    $new = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}
echo $new;
```

What it basically does is to check if the generated number from `$rand` is already in the database and will set a `$new` variable. My problem is when I echo out `$new`, I always get an `undefined index` of that variable. How can I call that variable outside the while loop?

Comment: What is the sense of this? Why would you overwrite that variable `$new` in all iterations? I assume you want to add a `break` or `continue` statement to that loop... Also: this will be an endless loop once there _is_ an entry in the database, since you do not modify `$accounts` inside the loop...

Comment: @arkascha thank you for pointing that out.. I forgot that. Should I use continue because I want it to go back to the condition when it is already present in the database

Comment: @arkascha Will I still get an endless loop with my code?

Comment: @arkascha Then I should use do while loop right?

Comment: I could imagine your want to use a `for` or a `foreach` loop instead of that while...

Comment: @arkascha That select * from accounts WHERE sponsorID = $rand

Comment: Sure, I guess so. But look at that while condition: why should the result of `count($accounts))` _ever_ change? Since you do not alter `$accounts` inside the loop it will _always_ return the same, no mater what. So either the loops is not executed at all (no entry in `$accounts`) or it will be an endless loop in all other cases. Use this instead: `foreach ($accounts as $account) { ... }` That will iterate exactly as many times as there are entries in `$accounts`.

Comment: @arkascha I don't get what you mean.. but what I wanted to do is when a random number is already existing in the accounts table, I want to generate a new one and will check again in the database until it becomes unique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84911/discussion-between-arkascha-and-fewflyby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. This is a modified version that outputs what you are looking for:

```
<?php 

$sid = array(
  ":sponsorID" => $rand
);
$accounts = $db->select("accounts", "sponsorID = :sponsorID", $sid);

$new = null; 
do { 
  $new = mt_rand(100000, 999999); 
} while (in_array($new, array_column($accounts, 'sponsorId'))); 

echo $new;
```

*Note: this requires at least php 5.5 because of the `array_column()` call. But that makes the code simple and easy to understand.*

Answer (score 3):

You are only defining `$new` inside the loop, so it's undefined outside it. Just declare it before the loop and you should be fine:

```
$new = NULL;
while (count($accounts) > 0) {
    $new = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
}
echo $new;
```

Comment: I always get null with this